# Position another image relatively to text with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

```
convert inputImage.jpeg -gravity South -size x32 label:"Morning in paradise" -geometry +0+40 -composite starImage.png -composite finalImage.png
```

With this command, I can add text at the bottom of inputImage and another image on this text. But how can I set (or prefix) the starImage image to the left of the text that has a dynamic width and fixed height. I have attached some images below to explain what I want to do.

[Obtained result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSi6Y.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEzN8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the star image, create the text label, and append them together inside parentheses. Then composite that assembled star-text image over the main input image. A command like this should get pretty near what you described.

```
convert inputImage.jpeg -gravity center -size x32 \
   \( starImage.png label:"Morning in paradise" +append \) \
   -geometry +0+40 -gravity South -composite finalImage.png
```

If you want a star on both sides of the line of text, you can read the "starImage.png" in once more after creating the label and before appending.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do using Imagemagick is to set the width you want for the text so that there is room for the star image to be append on each side and have some padding as well. Here is how I would do it. Since you did not provide your input or star image, I have simulated the image as a blue image and taken some graphic image that I had around to simulate your star or logo. I first measure the desired width. The width is 70% of the difference is width between the large blue image and twice the width of the logo. I append the logo on each side of the text image, then composite that near the bottom of the blue image to create your final image. If this were in Imagemagick 7, it could be done in one command. This is Unix syntax.

Image:

[image]

Logo:

[image]

```
width=`convert background.jpg logo.png -format "%[fx:0.70*(u.w-2*v.w)]\n" info: | head -n1`
convert background.jpg \
\( logo.png \
-size ${width}x -background none -fill black -font Arial -gravity center label:"THIS IS A TEST" \
logo.png \
+append \) \
-gravity south -geometry +0+50 \
-compose over -composite \
result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: As the text width may vary, I don't understand how you calculate it

Comment: `@chrisayn` I first measure the desired width. The width is 70% of the difference is width between the large blue image and twice the width of the logo. I use that width with label rather than the height. You can change that percent, if you want. The result is that the font height (point size) changes with the length. There is no way to keep the font height constant for any length or if the number of characters is too large, it will go off the image.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider giving it an up-vote